# Write the function that finds the index of an element in array of numbers

Tags: python, python-3.x

I made this to find the minimum value of the array of numbers:

`lst = [3, 71, 420, 14]
print ("Min number in array:", min(lst))`

But how do I find the index of an element in array of numbers?

Comment: By using the `.index()` method on your list?

Comment: This is so obviously homework, why was it not closed sooner!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `enumerate` to generate indices for each item in the list, and supply the `min` function with a key function that uses the second item of each tuple in the sequence generated by `enumerate`, and finally, use `[0]` to extract the index of the item with the minimum value returned by `min`:

```
from operator import itemgetter
print(min(enumerate(lst), key=itemgetter(1))[0])
```

This outputs: `0` (the index of `3` in your sample list)

Answer (score 0):

Simplest solution I can think of is via index:

```
lst.index(min(lst))
```